# Received the achievement and privilege to comment although cannot comment

Tags: support, privileges

So I recently got 40 points on SO (GO me!)

Then something popped up in my achievements icons and found this:

[image: achievements]

Although when I go to comment:

[image]

Comment: It’s possible that you temporarily received an upvote that pushed you to 50 reputation points which then granted you the permission resulting in the notification. And after that, the upvote was undone, so the +10 was again removed (resulting in your current 40 reputation points) causing the privilege to be removed again. This however will not clear achievements or general messages that were sent to your inbox.